# Site not looking good in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, wordpress

A site I constructed on wordpress, [www.instant-wine-cellar.co.uk](http://www.instant-wine-cellar.co.uk), does seem to be working well on Firefox web browser. I was wondering if any one could help me work out why that is (maybe using firebug). The stylesheet is a file called style.css and the reset stylesheet is reset.css. It looks normal in any other web browser.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks ok to me in FF 3.0.15 (unless I'm just overlooking something).  Did you already implement a fix?

(... man, I'd love to have a wooden wine cellar in my basement like that...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like CSS validation issue to me, here is what the ERROR CONSOLE shows in FF:

> Warning: Expected identifier in media
>   list but found '.'.  Expected ',' in
>   media list but found ':'.  Expected
>   ',' in media list but found ':'. 
>   Expected ',' in media list but found
>   '{'.  Expected ',' in media list but
>   found '#shippingdetails'.  Expected
>   ',' in media list but found
>   '#shippingdetails'.  Expected
>   identifier in media list but found
>   '#footer-wrapper-inside'.  Expected
>   identifier in media list but found
>   '#footer-wrapper-inside'.  Unexpected
>   end of file while searching for end of
>   media list in @import or @media rule. 
>   Unexpected end of file while searching
>   for ';'.
>
> Source File:
>   http://www.instant-wine-cellar.co.uk/wp-content/themes/Wineconcepts/style.css Line: 16

Comment: @seedorf Your last import needs a ';' on the end.

Comment: @Joel Meador: Yep, that's exactly it. After adding the semicolon, the site looks the same in FF and IE.

Comment: I would have given the correct answer to Joel but i'm not able to vote a comment. Thanks a lot for spotting that Joel!!